# Какой контрол использовать для выбора картинки пользователем?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windowsphone

Какой контрол использовать для выбора картинки пользователем? Те должен быть список картинок из которого можно выбрать картинку, а так же после выбора можно было видеть что он выбрал. А так же должна быть возможность программно обрабатывать выбор. 
Наже картинка я набрасал примерно как я вижу, не обязательно точь в точь, можно что то даже отдаленно напоминающее или же раскрывающийся список например... [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

GridView выглядит именно так, как вы хотите.